# Integer Linear Program, Bipartite Matching with Constraints How To?

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science, linear-programming, or-tools

The following program produces a matching between two sets of vertices, one represents meets between two teams and the other time slots when the meets could happen. The adjacency map represents both teams' availability to meet at any given time slot, days[][] represents which time slots are on the same date, weekDays[][] represents what day of the week is a given date, and teamToGames maps every meet that includes a given team. The decision variables are in a map match[][], with a value of 1 where a meet is matched to a time slot. Constraints are added so that only 1 meet can be matched to a time slot, only 1 time slot can be matched to a meet, only if allowed by the respective adj[][] value, and so that meets involving the same team cannot be matched to a game slot on the same date nor the following or previous date, excluding thursday-sunday.

What I don't know how to do now, is how can I make it prefer assigning two or more meets on the same date rather than one meet on each of two separate dates? So that there is the least possible amount of dates with only one meet. Kind of like constraining the number of meets on a date to either 0 or >=2 but only if possible.

Thank you for reading and for any help you can offer.

```
// [START program]
// [START import]
import com.google.ortools.linearsolver.MPConstraint;
import com.google.ortools.linearsolver.MPObjective;
import com.google.ortools.linearsolver.MPSolver;
import com.google.ortools.linearsolver.MPVariable;
// [END import]

/** MIP example that solves an assignment problem. */
public class GameMatching {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("jniortools");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Data
        // [START data_model]
        // Adjacency matrix represents which games can happen on which dates
        int[][] adj = {
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        };

        int numGames = adj.length;
        int numDates = adj[0].length;

        //represents which game time slots are on a given day (4 games on sundays, 2 on weekdays)
        int[][] days = {
              {0, 1, 2, 3},
              {4, 5},
              {6, 7},
              {8, 9, 10, 11},
              {12, 13},
              {14, 15},
              {16, 17},
              {18, 19},
              {20, 21, 22, 23},
              {24, 25},
              {26, 27},
              {28, 29},
              {30, 31},
              {32, 33, 34, 35},
              {36, 37},
              {38, 39},
              {40, 41},
              {42, 43},
              {44, 45, 46, 47},
              {48, 49},
              {50, 51},
              {52, 53, 54, 55},
              {56, 57},
              {58, 59},
              {60, 61},
              {62, 63},
              {64, 65, 66, 67},
              {68, 69},
              {70, 71},
              {72, 73},
              {74, 75},
              {76, 77, 78, 79}
        };
        //represents what day of the week is a day, a team can play thursday and sunday, but not sunday and monday 0 is sunday, 1 is monday...
        int[] weekDays = {0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0};

        // teamToGames[i][j] represents a team i's, games j
        int[][] teamToGames = {
              {1, 3, 9, 16, 18, 26},
              {0, 8, 12, 16, 23, 28},
              {1, 5, 7, 13, 21, 27},
              {2, 5, 14, 17, 22, 26},
              {7, 15, 19, 21, 24, 28},
              {3, 10, 14, 20, 27, 29},
              {2, 6, 9, 13, 23, 29},
              {6, 8, 11, 18, 19, 25},
              {8, 4, 10, 11, 17, 24},
              {4, 12, 15, 20, 22, 25},
        };
       
        // [END data_model]

        // Solver
        // [START solver]
        // Create the linear solver with the CBC backend.
        MPSolver solver = new MPSolver("AssignmentMip", MPSolver.OptimizationProblemType.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING);
        // [END solver]

        // Variables
        // [START variables]
        // x[i][j] is an array of 0-1 variables, which will be 1
        // if a game i is assigned to date j.
        MPVariable[][] match = new MPVariable[numGames][numDates];
        for (int i = 0; i < numGames; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numDates; ++j) {
                match[i][j] = solver.makeIntVar(0, 1, "");
            }
        }

        // [END variables]

        // Constraints
        // [START constraints]
        // Each game is assigned to at most one date.
        for (int i = 0; i < numGames; ++i) {
            MPConstraint constraint = solver.makeConstraint(0, 1, "");
            for (int j = 0; j < numDates; ++j) {
                constraint.setCoefficient(match[i][j], 1);
            }
        }
        // Each date is assigned to at most one game.
        for (int j = 0; j < numDates; ++j) {
            MPConstraint constraint = solver.makeConstraint(0, 1, "");
            for (int i = 0; i < numGames; ++i) {
                constraint.setCoefficient(match[i][j], 1);
            }
        }
        // Can only assign respecting adj matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < numGames; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numDates; ++j) {
                MPConstraint constraint = solver.makeConstraint(0, adj[i][j], "");
                constraint.setCoefficient(match[i][j], 1);
            }
        }

        // Cannot assign team to consecutive dates
        for (int i = 0; i < teamToGames.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < days.length - 1; ++j) {
                if (weekDays[j] != 4) {
                    MPConstraint constraint = solver.makeConstraint(0, 1, "");
                    for (int k = 0; k < teamToGames[i].length; ++k) {
                        for (int l = 0; l < days[j].length; ++l) {
                            constraint.setCoefficient(match[teamToGames[i][k]][l], 1);
                        }
                        for (int l = 0; l < days[j+1].length; ++l) {
                            constraint.setCoefficient(match[teamToGames[i][k]][l], 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // [END constraints]

        // Objective
        // [START objective]
        MPObjective objective = solver.objective();
        for (int i = 0; i < numGames; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numDates; ++j) {
                objective.setCoefficient(match[i][j], 1);
            }
        }

        objective.setMaximization();
        // [END objective]

        // Solve
        // [START solve]
        MPSolver.ResultStatus resultStatus = solver.solve();
        // [END solve]

        // Print solution.
        // [START print_solution]
        // Check that the problem has a feasible solution.
        if (resultStatus == MPSolver.ResultStatus.OPTIMAL || resultStatus == MPSolver.ResultStatus.FEASIBLE) {
            System.out.println("Total matches: " + objective.value() + "\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < numGames; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numDates; ++j) {
                    // Test if x[i][j] is 0 or 1 (with tolerance for floating point
                    // arithmetic).
                    if (match[i][j].solutionValue() > 0.5) {
                        System.out.println("Game " + i + " assigned to date " + j);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("No solution found.");
        }
        // [END print_solution]
    }

    // private GameMatching() {
    // }
}
// [END program]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing a page from the facility location playbook, make a new array of 0-1 variables `canHaveMatches[j]`, add constraints `match[i][j] <= canHaveMatches[j]`, minimize `sum_j canHaveMatches[j]`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand the logic but OR Tools doesn't let me set an MPVariable as a bound for a constraint, it only takes doubles. How can I do that? Also can you have two objectives in a linear program? Sorry, first time doing anything related to lp here.

Comment: @vsoued Ah, you rewrite as `match[i][j] - canHaveMatches[j] <= 0`. What's the other objective?

Comment: Thank you that makes sense! The other, and I'd say principal, objective is to maximize the number of matches made.

Comment: @vsoued In that case I'd try to maximize the number of matches without these new constraints, then re-solve the program to minimize the number of days subject to these constraints and the new constraint that the number of matches equal the optimum from the previous phase.